# How to run one project on two domains?

Tags: apache-2.2

How to run one project on two domains?

My try: (but not working, only first `mydomain.com` work)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com *.mydomain.com

        Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/static/
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/index.wsgi


        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName otherdomain.com
        ServerAlias otherdomain.com *.otherdomain.com

        Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/static/
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/index.wsgi


        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the apache documentation:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName server.domain.com
ServerAlias server server2.domain.com server2
ServerAlias *.example.com
UseCanonicalName Off
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias